# How route works with viewsets? the router does not generate views based on "basename"?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In the doc it says that in some cases it may not be possible to generate views in some cases, so I have one: AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have to`. queryset` attribute.

Okay, so I'm inserting a basename:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("links", links_views.LinkViewSet, basename="links")
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls))
]
```

So when I access the url, it raises the error: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "link-detail".

That is, it generates the unsupported views I inserted into "basename" (in this case, it generates vews in the singular name, "link-detail" instead "links-detail")

And if I change "basename" to anything else, it does not work.

But when I simply enter a basename, using using the name of the view that appears in the error, resulting in:

```
router.register("links", links_views.LinkViewSet, basename="link")
```

I can access urls normally.

Why does this work that way? I read the doc but I can not understand this behavior